# Query on assembly prefix 'times'

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, bootloader

Below is the assembly code that I would like to understand. How 512 bytes are populated after this code is assembled with nasm?

Because I am still not clear about the meaning of `510-($-$$)` doing here? What is the value of `$` and `$$` as per this below code?

http://www.brokenthorn.com/Resources/OSDev3.html

```
;***************************

org 0x7c00              ; We are loaded by BIOS at 0x7C00

bits    16              ; We are still in 16 bit Real Mode

Start:

    cli             ; Clear all Interrupts
    hlt             ; halt the system

times 510 - ($-$$) db 0   ; We have to be 512 bytes. Clear the rest of the bytes with 0

dw 0xAA55           ; Boot Signature

;*********************
```

Answer (score 3):

From [NASM manual](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html), Section "3.5 Expressions":

> NASM supports two special tokens in expressions, allowing calculations to involve the current assembly position: the $ and $$ tokens. $ evaluates to the assembly position at the beginning of the line containing the expression; so you can code an infinite loop using JMP $. $$ evaluates to the beginning of the current section; so you can tell how far into the section you are by using ($-$$).

So, the code above does the following:

1. Calculates how many bytes 'cli' and 'hlt' instructions take N = $-$$. That will be 0x7C02-0x7C00=2, since both instructions take 1 byte each.
2. Reserves (510-N) zero bytes ([repeating](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.15.05/html/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.2.5) the `db 0` the calculated number of times).
   That will be 508 bytes, for N=2 bytes of instructions before this point.
3. Reserves a word 0xAA55 taking 2 bytes.

The intent is to have a 512-byte block: N + ( 510 - N ) + 2 = 512

Comment: Start: label tell us that this is the starting point for the assembly code. So for your question: "Calculates how many bytes 'cli' and 'hlt' instructions take" This two instructions take 2 bytes so $ = 0x7C00 and $$ = 0x7C02(beginning of the times line) so i think the expression for times prefix is going as (510-($-$$)) = (510 -(0x7C00-0x7C02)) = (510 - (-2)) = 512, so it is 'times 512 db 0' which will set 0's to 512 bytes.

Comment: So, If my above update is correct, My question is, if 'times 512 db 0' is at address 0x7C02, 'times' will set 512 bytes as 0's starting from this address(0x7C02) rather than 0x7C00? so are we not missing first two bytes and zeroing extra 2 bytes at the end? Hope you understood my doubt.

Comment: It is vice versa: $$=0x7C00 <- start of the section; $=0x7C02 <- start of the "times" line. So, times will set 508 bytes to 0 starting from 0x7C02. The sum of all will be 2 [cli+hlt] + 508 [times db] + 2 [dw] => 512 bytes. I;ve updated the answer with the example calculation on x86 processor.

Comment: shamuddin mohd: please mark the answer as "correct" if it helped you.